# Javascript parseInt() function only works once?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and have a question on turning stings to numbers using parseInt() function.

I was practicing parseInt by writing the below code and used typeof to check the data type in console before mutating the user input from string to number. After displaying the result, I used console log again to check the data type, and it is still string.

Does parseInt() only transform once during this statement run and returns to original state afterwards? Original state meaning the state in which the code was initially written. In this case, HTMLBadges prompts the user to enter a string.

```
let HTMLBadges = prompt("How many HTML badges have you earned?");
let CSSBadges = prompt("How many CSS badges have you earned?");

console.log(typeof HTMLBadges + typeof CSSBadges);

totalBadges = parseInt(HTMLBadges) + parseInt(CSSBadges);

console.log(`You have a total of ${totalBadges} badges!`);

console.log(typeof HTMLBadges + typeof CSSBadges);
```

Comment: `parseInt` doesn't change the argument. It returns a new integer but the argument keeps unchanged.

Comment: and why not? you aren't assigning it to the variable, you are not doing `HTMLBadges = parseInt(HTMLBadges)`

Comment: Strings are immutable in javascript. Which is a fancy way of saying, we cannot mutate the original. You'll need to save mutations to a variable if you want to access them later.

Answer (score 2):

`parseInt` returns a `number`, but it doesn't mutate the original variable in place.

Try your code and add the following to the end of it:

```
let numberVersion = parseInt(HTMLBadges)
console.log(typeof numberVersion)
```

You'll see that the result of `parseInt` inside `numberVersion`, is in fact, a number, but again, the original variable `HTMLBadges` doesn't get mutated during the call.

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Can I be efficient on the code and combine assignment and mutation together, so I can prompt the user to provide the value, and at the same time change it to a number? Something like" 

```
let HTMLBadges = parseInt(HTMLBadges.prompt("How many HTML badges have you earned?"));
```

Comment: Almost. You wouldn't call `HTMLBadges.prompt` though -- just `parseInt(prompt("..."))`. Keep in mind that you probably want to test for errors (like it not being a number). If this answer has solved your problem, feel free to click the checkmark to accept it.